# How to add `v => v` function as default value of function parameter correctly?

Tags: typescript

```js
function aFunction<T, NT extends Record<string, string | number | boolean>>(
  data: T,
  normalize: (data: T) => NT,
) {
  const normalizedData = normalize(data);

  return Object.keys(normalizedData);
}

aFunction(10, (v) => v);
// Error(Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string | number | boolean>')
// what it is CORRECT

aFunction(10, (data) => ({ data }));
// No error
// what it is CORRECT

aFunction({ data: 10 }, (v) => v);
// No error
// what it is CORRECT

function bFunction<T, NT extends Record<string, string | number | boolean>>(
  data: T,
  normalize: (data: T) => NT = (v) => v, 
   // ERROR: Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'NT'.
   // 'NT' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'
) {
  const normalizedData = normalize(data);

  return Object.keys(normalizedData);
}

bFunction(10); 
// no error
// what it is INCORRECT, should throw en error

bFunction(10, (data) => ({ data }));
// WORKS
// what it is CORRECT

bFunction({ data: 10 });
// WORKS
// what it is CORRECT
```

Function `aFunction` works correct - how I wanted to, but I would like to make `normalize` param not required and give it default value. I tried to do like in `bFunction`, but first of all I have an error, where I added default value. Next: in first case usage of in code above there should be error.

How to rewrite `bFunction` to meet my requirements? If it is possible. I was trying to do with conditional typing, but I've failed.

Comment: It seems like the best approach here might be to use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). Does this approach ([playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOLOMN)) help?

Comment: @spender - I thought about earlier, but I overdid sth. Today on fresh I came with implementation, but I'd still like to take suggestion to improve. I'm going to post it as an answer.

Comment: i see a few sample inputs, but can you show what output you are expecting? it seems odd to construct a record but then only return `Object.keys`.

Comment: The outputs don't matter - it is more about handling errors correctly and this implementation of function itself is simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with solution after @spender suggestion.

```js
type ConditionalType<H, K> = H extends K ? H : never;

function aFunction<T extends Record<string, string | number | boolean>>(
  data: T,
): string[];
function aFunction<T, NT extends Record<string, string | number | boolean>>(
  data: T,
  normalize: (data: T) => NT,
): string[];
function aFunction<T, NT extends Record<string, string | number | boolean>>(
  data: T, 
  normalize: (data: T) => NT = (v) => v as ConditionalType<T, NT>
) {
  const normalizedData = normalize(data);

  return Object.keys(normalizedData);
}
```

But I'm still not super happy with using my `ConditionalType`. I'm open for suggestion.